# Custom Membership Provider and ChangePassword control

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have implemented a Custom `Membership` provider for my existing database schema with the help of the following link

I have overridden the following methods `CreateUSer`, `ValidateUser`, `GetUser`, `ChangePassword` and `ResetPassword`.
For the `ChangePassword` method , it validates the new password for the Minimum length and also for the Number of Alphanumeric characters. If the validation fails the method throws an Argument Exception with the exact error.

The problem what I face is, I am using the built in Change password control, I get the following error, `"Argumnet exception was unhandled in user code"` .

Also it displays a generic error

```
"Password incorrect or New Password invalid."
```

I would rather want to display the exact reason of the error why the password validation failed.

How do i go abou implementhing this. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Thanks

Comment: which link you talking about? have a look at ChangePassword class in MSDN which might give you a better idea

Comment: have you enabled password retrieval?i would suggest you post the overridden change password method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likley in your implementation the [virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.23) [`MembershipUser.ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx)  From the MSDN article, it needs to take 2 parameters:

```
oldPassword
    Type:System.String
    The current password for the membership user.
newPassword
    Type:System.String
    The new password for the membership user.
```

Without seeing you ChangePassword function, I would guess that you are

1. Not passing the "oldPassword" argument, or
2. Passing a value that's not a string as one of those 2 arguments.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, what you really want to do is handle the [ChangePasswordError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.changepassworderror.aspx) event of the ChangePassword control.  This will let you provide custom feedback when an error is raised.

Comment: The method signature is correct. I used the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx   What I want to know is how to catch the Exceptions raised in the provider in the ChangePassword control.

Comment: @user I've added another link to my answer.  As far as I know, you can't actually get the error from the MembershipProvider, but you could do additional processing in the event I linked to determine the reason.

Comment: The ChangePasswordError event  does not indicate the reason why changing the password failed, only that the password was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  It appears you'll have to use a regular form and create error handling to display the message you would like instead of the built in message that appears.